# How to press enter during booting without keyboard on ubuntu?

Tags: boot, linux, raspi-config

I updated my raspberry pi 3.
Now every time I boot it says:

> cannot open access to console root account is locked. Press enter to boot

I am able to boot when I press enter using the keyboard. I want to know is there any other way to fix this as this message always pops up during boot.

I am also not able to ssh into the pi.
P.S: I don't have a keyboard anymore.

Comment: If you have another computer with serial interface and depending on Raspberry Pi model (This fact is missing) then you can either use the serial via GPIO or USB. or get a keyboard.

Comment: then after every reboot, i have to do the same?